# How to do mulitple different replace of same regex pattern xxx but with replacement also containing xxx

Tags: javascript, regex

Let say I have

```
1XXX, 2XXX
```

I want to replace XXX by respectively (remark that it contains XXX again)

```
AXXX, B
```

which would give

```
1AXXX, 2B
```

I can't see if it is possible to do so with just regex (I'm a beginner at regex)?

https://regex101.com/r/xk9iSx/1

Comment: If its a string you can use the same regex. If its an array you have to check each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let input = "1XXX, 2XXX";
// Then we need an iterator over the replacement texts
let replacements = ["AXXX", "B"][Symbol.iterator]();
// Finally we call replace.
let result = input.replace(
    // A RegExp with `g` replaces every occurrence in input
    /XXX/g,
    // And we use a replacer function that pulls 
    // values from replacements.
    () => replacements.next().value
);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result)); // => 1AXXX, 2B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the character before the `XXX` and use that to decide what to replace with:

```js
const original = "1XXX, 2XXX";
const result = original.replace(/(\d)XXX/g, (m, c0) =>
    `${c0}${c0 === "1" ? "AXXX" : "B"}`
);
console.log(result);
```

The function you pass as a second argument to `replace` receives the total match as its first argument followed by additional arguments for any capture groups in the expression. The expression `/(\d)XXX/g` looks for and digit followed by `XXX` and *captures* the digit. So the function can see that the first capture group value (`c0`) is `"1"` and use `<the captured value>AXXX` as the replacement, otherwise using `"<the captured value>B"`.

This can be generalized with a lookup table or `Map`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't your solution depend on the number of terms I mean what if I have more than 2 ?

Comment: @user310291 - It's not dependent on the number of items, no; it is dependent on the digit being matched. `"1XXX, 2XXX, 1XXX, 2XXX, 1XXX"` becomes `"1AXXX, 2B, 1AXXX, 2B, 1AXXX"` for instance.  That's what I meant about how it could be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this approach of keeping replacements in an array and using an index to keep track of replacement number:

```js
var s = '1XXX, 2XXX, 3XXX, 4XXX';
var repl = ['AXXX', 'B'];
var len = repl.length-1;

var i=-1; // index counter
var r = s.replace(/XXX/g, (m) => repl[i = (i >= len ? 0 : i+1)]);

console.log(r);
//=> "1AXXX, 2B, 3AXXX, 4B"
```